# PHP and JavaScript together

Tags: javascript, php, html, database, forms

**COMPLETE REVISION:**

This code is the whole problem:

```
function Inbox() {
    #Connecting:
    include('config.php');
    $MyConnection = new PDO('mysql:host=x;dbname=x', $dbusername, $dbpassword);
    $MyConnection->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

    #Collecting:
    $curUser = $_SESSION['name'];

    #Searching:
    $searchInbox = $MyConnection->prepare("SELECT * FROM Inbox WHERE To = :username");
    $searchInbox->bindParam(':username', $curUser);
    $searchInbox->execute();
    $foundResults = $searchInbox->fetch(PDO::FETCH_BOTH);
    var_dump($foundResults);
  }
```

As soon as I add in the 'Searching' code, I get a 404 error, as if it tries to refer to another webpage.

A picture of my Database table 'Inbox':
[image]
When I replace:

```
$searchInbox = $MyConnection->prepare("SELECT * FROM Inbox WHERE To = :username");
```

To:
$searchInbox = $MyConnection->prepare("SELECT * FROM Inbox WHERE Title = Welcome");

I get the following error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'Welcome' in 'where clause'' in (..)
```

So, somehow it can't read the Title column in this case? And why does it not read the whole 'To' column and returns a 404 error?

Comment: your action attribute is empty, first of all --- which should link to that final block of code --

Comment: @MackieeE, It seemed to have disappeared, but I still get the 404 error whenever I click on the link. (See code for some revisions).

Comment: @rm-vanda, that the action attribute is empty should not be (the) problem. As the empty space also refers to the current page.

Comment: Click on what link?  Where is the rest of your code??

Comment: @SyntaxLAMP, They will not have to click a link, they will have to click the button. Because so far I've not been able to get the JavaScript to load the PHP-function 'Inbox()'.

Comment: Can you paste in the precise 404 error? "Index.php is not found?" - at the top of your index.php, do if($_POST) { print_r($_POST); die(); } and also enable error reporting via: 
ini_set("display_errors",1);
ini_set("display_startup_errors",1);
error_reporting(-1);

Comment: @rm-vanda, Somehow now I get: Array ( [submit-inbox] => Inbox )

Comment: I do not think button items get sent as POST values, so isset($_POST["submit-inbox"]) will always be false.

Comment: It's a submit button, not a regular button. Therefore it will work.

Comment: I dont think submit buttons send data either.  Obviously it's not working...

Comment: It´s a form, whenever I´d use `<form blah blah> <input type="text" blah blah /> <input type="submit" /></form>` It will send data, it's a form. It's designed to do that.

Comment: @SyntaxLAMP, what part of it?

Comment: I do not think submit buttons will get sent the same way as text boxes do.  I think the isset() code you have will always be false because submit buttons do not get sent with post.  Add <input type="hidden" name ="submit-inbox2"> and check isset on that input field instead.

Comment: How about the whole code?  Youre only including what you think is important, but obviously you dont know the problem

Comment: Done. By the way, I also use `$_POST['submit-login']` for example, to make a user login.

Comment: @SyntaxLAMP, and then it went quiet. :/ I hope the code will be any useful.

Comment: type="submit" does, in fact, show up in the $_POST.

Comment: @rm-vanda, I've uploaded all the files that are related to this problem, all of them, in its entirely.

Comment: Yeah, my fault, I saw that right after I commented --- Are you sure that $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] actually points to the right file? Why don't you try hardcoding that-- and dont't forget to take out that debugging code I gave you -

Comment: @rm-vanda, as you can see I already have put that into the code. The `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` can also be removed as it is more data that has to be calculated. Leaving the action attribute empty will serve the same purpose.

Comment: @rm-vanda, Yet, when I remove your debugging code, I get the 404 error again. With the debugging code I get `Array ( [submit-inbox] => Inbox )` presented on a white page.

Comment: What happens if you make the action "mypage.php"?

Comment: @SyntaxLAMP, I still get the 404 error.

Comment: What page is being requested that is showing the 404?  What URL is in the addressbar?

Comment: The hosting service I work with (free personal hosting service, so I am very limited with traffic, data storage, etc.) shows their own 404 error, and there's no way (as far as I'm aware of) to know what url is being processed.

Comment: What is shown in the addressbar when you get the 404?

Comment: @SyntaxLAMP, http://errors.biz.nf/404.php

Comment: My antivirus won't let me see that page, but I'm guessing it just says 404.  Well, my guess is that the $_SESSION["name"] is not getting set, and at the top of mypage.php it is then redirecting to the askmephilosophy login page.

Comment: @SyntaxLAMP, The mypage.php file does get loaded. And when one is not logged in one will get sent back to the login.php page, so it does work. I had this 404 problem a couple times earlier than this, as I transferred the  `Login() { ...}` function from the login.php file to the functions.php file. After rewriting the code a couple of times, somehow it did not display the 404 error anymore. I've done the same with this, though it still doesn't work. I'm really confused by the 404 occurrence.

Comment: @SyntaxLAMP, When I replace the code of the `Login()` function with `echo 'It's working there's no 404 error here!` I do get the echo on my screen. So there's probably a fault within code that has to do with the database, rather than the code of the submit-button.

Comment: @SyntaxLAMP, As soon as I add the `$searchInbox->prepare(..)` etc. The code tries to refers to a page that doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

If you would like JavaScript to be able to call the PHP function and then update the inbox with the response take a look at [Ajax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX). You can use this to send parameters to a php file, receive a response, and process the response and update the page with JavaScript. If you even want, [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) has a very nice Ajax function you can use.

Answer (score 0):

Ah, okay- we may be getting closer --- 
It looks like you've got something redirecting, somewhere --

Since $_POST shows up alongside a die statement, then it seems like that's really the only thing it could be --

To illustrate my point, try this:

```
if($_POST){
     if($_POST['submit-inbox'] == "Inbox"){
          Inbox(); die("if you can read this, then you have a header('Location: '); or perhaps even a javascript somewhere that is directing you to a page that doesn't exist"); 
     } else { echo "something really effin weird is going on"; 
          print_r($_POST); 
     }
}
```

You know -- just pop that in instead of the `if($_POST) [...] die();`

Comment: I still get the 404 error. Somehow it's redirecting me to a page that doesn't exist? I'm very confused right now.

Comment: What about that $_SESSION['name'] statement with the header() ? 
That wasn't showing up as a 404, though ---

Comment: one more short on what part? The `$_SESSION['name']`? I've already replaced that with `$curUser` at the `$MyConnection->query()` though it did not help.